# Cmake is not adding directories correctly with "target_link_directory"

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I Ubuntu, I am learning about cmake and make, and just trying a simple example. I have two directories: `src` and `build`. In `src`, I have three files: `main.cpp`, `camera.hpp`, and `CMakeLists.txt`, which has (only) the following text:

```
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_directory(/home/karnivaurus/Libraries)
target_link_libraries(test Camera)
```

In `/home/karnivaurus/Libraries`, I have a shared library called `libCamera.so`, which I want to link against. My `main.cpp` uses functions in this library, which are declared in `camera.hpp`.

Now, in my `build` directory, I run `cmake ../src`, and then `make`. However, I then get linker errors telling me that there are undefined references to some of the functions in my library. If I do a search through all the files and subdirectories in `build`, there is not mention of `libCamera.so`.

However, if I remove the `target_link_directory` line in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, and instead write the full path to the library when specifying the executable, i.e. `target_link_libraries(test /home/karnivaurus/Libraries/libCamera.so)`, it compiles and links fine.

Why is `target_link_directory` not working as expected?

Answer (score 5):

This may help someone someday.

You should use the `target_link_directories` after `add_executable`

Example:

`add_executable(main main.cpp)`

Then

`target_link_directories(target PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE directory)`

So your end result may look like

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_directories(main INTERFACE /my/libs/dir)
```

or

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_directories(main PUBLIC /my/libs/dir)
```

or

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_directories(main PRIVATE /my/libs/dir)
```

Unfortunately, CMake does not encourage this, you should instead link the actual library you want

```
target_link_libraries (main /my/awesome/lib.so)
```

There is also another way to link directories.

```
link_directories(/my/libs/dir)
```

> Check the official documentation
>   (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_directories.html)

Comment: documentation claims target_link_directories is supported starting in 3.13, but doesn't work for me in 3.23.1

Answer (score 4):

Use command `link_directories()` instead of `target_link_directories()` (which does not exist):

```
add_executable(test main.cpp)
link_directories(/home/karnivaurus/Libraries)
target_link_libraries(test Camera)
```

NOTE: My CMake issued an error when it saw the command `target_link_directory()` I wonder why you did not see it (CMake 2.8.12).

Comment: Note that link_directories must be called before the call to add_executable

Comment: @Julien-L for info `target_link_directories()` is currently feature requested cf https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17215

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `target_link_directory` used, and don't find the relevant documentation in CMake manual.

If you want to link with `libCamera.so` in `/home/username/Libraries`, you may simply write CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main /home/username/Libraries/libCamera.so)
```

If there're many libraries you want to link against, you may consider using `find_library` which accepts `PATHS` option. Something like this:

```
find_library(MY_CAMERA_LIBRARY Camera PATHS /home/username/Libraries)
message(STATUS "MY_CAMERA_LIBRARY: " ${MY_CAMERA_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(main ${MY_CAMERA_LIBRARY})
```

MY_CAMERA_LIBRARY variable will be set to the full path to your libCamera.so.